# Dumping bits/bytes to a file in binary mode

Tags: c, file

I have below code.

```
FILE *fp;
int a;
fp=fopen("dump.bin","wb");         
a = 0xffafbcdf;
fprintf(fp,"%x",a&0x3ffff);
```

I am trying to dump only 18 LSBits of variable a. But the value dumped in the file is 3bcdf.

My question - Is it not possible to dump/fwrite/fprintf desired number of bits which is not a multiple of 4(nibble) to a file?

EDIT:

1.) When I checked the output of my file dump I realized, since I am opening file in binary mode, I should not be using `fprintf`, but I should use `fwrite`.

2.) What I see in the output is `DF BC 03` , it writes in multiples of 8 bits, so it writes 24 bits(3 bytes) but i was interested in only 18 bits. But then I realized that no  file write library will be able to write non-multiple of 8 bits to a file. it will always add leading zero bits to complete the byte and then dump it. "Least count unit"  for a file data is a byte.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't write part of a byte to a file. You have to write  full bytes. If you want another process to read only 18 bits, you'll need to either make it read 18 bits specifically, or write the # of bits to the file (e.g. in the first 4 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the character is the minimal sized entity you can write to a file.  I'd just like to observe that there is nothing wrong with using fprintf() (or any other stream output function) on binary files.

Comment: @Neil: If i used a fprintf() to write to file then it was dumping the ascii values for bytes 3 b c d f, i.e. file contained 32 62 63 64 66. Where as fwrite was dumping df bc 03.

Comment: Yes, they do different things, but they are both equally valid functions to use with binary files.

Answer (score 0):

`0x3bcdf` are the 18 LSBits of `0xffafbcdf`, so it seems to be working as expected. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Files are written in bytes (8 bits), not nibbles (4bits).

*Edit after your edit:* fprintf will print text, thus you'll get 6 bytes, where-as if you used fwrite you will write an int (32 bit) to a file, but masking the value recorded.